# Transformer of a pipeline acts on the training data instead of the whole data in GridSearchCV

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using pipeline and GridSearchCV to select features automatically. Since the data set is small, I set the parameter 'cv' in GridSearchCV to StratifiedShuffleSplit. The code looks like as follows:

```
selection = SelectKBest()

clf = LinearSVC()

pipeline = Pipeline([("select", selection), ("classify", clf)])

cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=50)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, cv = cv)

grid_search.fit(X, y)
```

It seems that SelectKBest acts on the training data of each split instead of the whole data set (the latter is what I want) since the result becomes different if I separate the 'select' and 'classify', where the StratifiedShuffleSplit will for sure only act on the classifier.

What is the correct way of using pipeline and GridSearchCV in this case? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-validating the whole pipeline (i.e. running SelectKBest only on training part of each split) is the way to go. Otherwise the model is  allowed to look at the test part - it means quality estimates become wrong. Best hyperparameters found with these unfair quality estimates may also work worse on a real unseen data.

At prediction time you're not going to re-run SelectKBest on (training dataset + example to be predicted) and then re-train the classifier, why would you do that in evaluation?

Comment: This is the correct link for the paper http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btp621 which discusses this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the answer of this question from page 245 to page 246 in the book-"The elements of statistical learning (2rd edition)" by Hastie,etc.